# Setting the Logfile for dpkg from apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, dpkg

I am writing a custom install script with multiple `apt-get install` commands. What I am looking at is to change the `dpkg` log file path.

The problem I am facing is that in order for me to do so, I have to change the `dpkg.conf` file.

Instead of that, is there a way by which I can send a parameter through `apt-get` (or set it somewhere in `apt.conf.d`) which updates the `--log` option of `dpkg`?

Comment: Why would you want to change the `dpkg` log file?

Comment: Unfortunately not my call. Thats a requirement thats come through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify dpkg options to apt via its Dpkg::Options configuration under /etc/apt/, or even from the command-line. Such as:

```
apt-get -oDpkg::Options::=--log=/path/to/other.log install pkgname
```

For more information please check the apt and apt.conf man pages.